# how to transform a part of a xml to a new xml without namespace?

Tags: xslt

I have trouble in transform part of a xml to a new xml without namespace.
Input xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<node1 xmlns="http://a.com">
    <ServiceData>
        <b:test xmlns:b="http://b.com">
            <b:somtag>
            </b:somtag>
        </b:test>
    </ServiceData>
</node1>
```

and what I want is:

```
<a>
    <c>
        <ServiceData>
            <b:test xmlns:b="http://b.com">
                <b:somtag>
                </b:somtag>
            </b:test>
        </ServiceData>
    </c>
</a>
```

The format I want is with no namespace for ServiceData.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Added, I tried to use this xsl, but I can't remove "xmlns="http://a.com""

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:test="http://a.com" exclude-result-prefixes="test">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <a><c><ServiceData><xsl:copy-of select="//test:ServiceData/*"/></ServiceData></c></a>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result I got is:

```
<a>
    <c>
        <ServiceData>
            <b:test xmlns:b="http://b.com" xmlns="http://a.com">
            <b:somtag>
            </b:somtag>
        </b:test>
        </ServiceData>
    </c>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xpath-default-namespace="http://a.com">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/node1">
    <a>
        <c>
            <ServiceData>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ServiceData/*" copy-namespaces="no" />
            </ServiceData>
        </c>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

I assumed you could use an XSLT 2.0 processor, because your stylesheet says `version="2.0"`. If that's not true, then you cannot use `xsl:copy-of`; instead, you must reconstruct the elements with their original names and namespaces:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:test="http://a.com" 
exclude-result-prefixes="test">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/test:node1">
    <a>
        <c>
            <ServiceData>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="test:ServiceData/*"/>
            </ServiceData>
        </c>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Note:

A redundant namespace declaration should not make any difference to the receiving application. The results received here are semantically identical to the result you show in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure if it work in your environment, but I only got  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> left.

Comment: @Conquer probably you were running it with an XSLT 1.0 processor. (If you give a 2.0 stylesheet to a 1.0 processor, it will ignore the parts it doesn't understand, like the `xpath-default-namespace` and `copy-namespaces` attributes, which are key to the way this stylesheet works).

Comment: @MichaelKaym, is there any way to realize this by xsl1?

Comment: @Conquer See the addition to my post.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, thanks a lot, this worked for me. Because I use this transform in Java Spring framework, and I quite don't know how to change to XSL2 processor.